# Are there any advantages of treating four-dimensional Euclidean space as $\mathbb{C}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question

When we treat four-dimensional Euclidean space as $\mathbb{R}^4$ we can easily define a line, plane, and 3-plane by linear equations, whereas if we wish to do the same with $\mathbb{C}^2$ we have a harder time with lines and 3-planes. Are there any circumstances where using $\mathbb{C}^2$ is easier?

Comment: What do you mean by easier?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a complex vector space (among other things). Expressing the complex eigenvector/eigenvalue pairs is going to be messier and less natural in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Yes, e.g. for the Hopf fibration, IIRC there is a bice formulation of the map $S^3\to S^2$ in terms of complex multiplication (to see it, look at the fact that the action of $S^1$ on $S^3$ can neatly be defined coordinatewise by complex multiplication)

Comment: What @Max described, also known as the hopf bundle is: let's say we want to move from $S^3$ to $S^2$, so let's say $(a,b,c,d)\iff (z_0,z_1)=(a+ib, c+id)$ and $(a,b,c)\iff (z,x)=(a+ib,c)$(move from $\Bbb R^4$ and $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb C^2,\Bbb C\times\Bbb R$). Now let's define Hopf bundle as $$p:S^3\to S^2\\(z_0,z_1)\mapsto (2z_0\bar{z}_1,|z_0|^2-|z_1|^2).$$This is just an example for such bundle.